# How to upgrade GNOME to the next unstable development series?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, software-installation, ppa, testing

I understand that with GNOME version numbers, you have the odd numbered releases being the unstable in-development series, and the even ones as the stable releases which the odd unstable ones become. So for instance I am currently running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I installed GNOME 3.18 from the [gnome3](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3) and [gnome3-staging](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging) PPAs in order to get there because Ubuntu GNOME is shipped with GNOME 3.16 due to issues with the release cycles of Ubuntu and GNOME not quite matching up so the latest version of GNOME is ready only after the time GNOME can submit the GNOME version to be used in the next Ubuntu release.

Anyway, as I like to be on the edge with software I'm using I would like to know if there is any way for me to easily upgrade to the [GNOME 3.19.x](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointNineteen) development series? Like is there a PPA or something I can get it with and stay up-to-date easily? And do I have to run Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 in order to do it or can it run on 15.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install GNOME 3.19.x from those PPAs (though it may not fully be in the PPAs yet) if you install one of the [Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 daily-builds](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/daily-live/current/). Otherwise you will have to wait for GNOME 3.20 to be available from them once Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 has been released.

As you can see though the GNOME 3.19.x versions are in the PPAs though:

[image]

Comment: If I installed one of the [Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 daily-builds](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/daily-live/current/) would I be able to get it from these PPAs then (or at least partly as they may not upload all of the packages there)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok, I have edited your answer to say that, just letting you know so that you can correct anything there if you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a github for `gnome-shell` , which you could clone

```
git clone https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell
```

And build the new version form source to stay up to date.

There's also [git for the gnome packages](https://git.gnome.org), for example for gedit you'd do this

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gedit
```

Comment: But if one wants to use, for example, gedit from Git, one still has to upgrade to a release that supports the current GTK dev build from the Staging PPA (or just build GTK from Git) in order to compile.